# POM error in Spring STS trying to set-up Spring Integration Sample

Tags: maven, spring-boot, spring-integration

Spring Boot / Spring Integration Sample Project: cafe-dsl

Error Message:
Missing artifact org.springframework.integration.samples:cafe-si:jar:4.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT

Description:After installing Spring STS (3.7) and installing the maven(3.3) project cafe-dsl. I get the error message above. I am using the maven embedded with Spring STS. Is there something I need to configure additionally so that it will properly build the project?

GIT Repo: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples.git

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you this project (`cafe-dsl`) requires another Spring Integration Sample project:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.integration.samples</groupId>
  <artifactId>cafe-si</artifactId>
  <version>4.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

Since it is a `BUILD-SNAPSHOT` and you'd like do not open the entire Spring Integration Samples project you just should add `snapshot` repo to the POM:

```
<repository>
  <id>repo.spring.io.snapshot</id>
  <name>Spring Framework Maven Snapshot Repository</name>
  <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot</url>
</repository>
```

**UPDATE**

The previous expression regarding the `libs-snapshot` and relying on the `cafe-si` from there was wrong. Since we don't `install` those samples projects as artifacts to the Maven repository it won't work that way.

I can confirm that it works only after these manipulations:

1. `gredlew install` from the root of Spring Integration Samples
2. This modifications to the `cafe-dsl` POM:

   ```
   <plugin>
       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
       <configuration>
            <mainClass>org.springframework.integration.samples.dsl.cafe.lambda.Application</mainClass>
       </configuration>        
     </plugin>
      <plugin>
       <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
       <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
       <version>3.3</version>
       <configuration>
         <source>1.8</source>
         <target>1.8</target>
       </configuration>
     </plugin>
   ```
3. And this Maven command:

   ```
     mvn spring-boot:run
   ```

Even if we can fix the POM generation from project perspective, I'm not sure that will `install` those artifacts to the `libs-snapshot` repo afterwards...

How about just rely on the Gradle?

Comment: I added the repo above and it still failed same error. I even tried a mvn install externally in the directory and it still failed same error.

Comment: I wonder how does it work from command line for you... Without any IDE integration. From other side is it so difficult for your to open the whole Spring Integration Samples from your STS? That should load all required dependencies.

Comment: I just maven outside of the IDE and run mvn install on the pom. Gives the same error. Yes I can check out the root samples directory and that works , however I would think I should be able to check out 1 spring project as stand alone to work with without having to bring in the whole repo.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback! Let me play with that locally.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed investigation. Would you say this is a defect on what's checked in by the Spring Integration team? I have never used gradle but I guess no time like the present.

Comment: Yeah... It is like defect, but I'm not sure that we would be able to fix all those vulnerabilities. Because of the Maven <-> Gadle interaction lack...